# If $\tau$ and $\tau'$ define the same borel sets, then $\tau=\tau'$

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets, polish-spaces, polish-groups

I have a group $G$ with two topologies $\tau, \tau'$ on $G$ that makes it a Polish group (a completely metrizable and separable topological group). I need to show that if $\mathcal{B}(\tau)=\mathcal{B}(\tau') $ , that is they define the same borel sets, then we have $\tau=\tau'$.

I just tried the obvious, I suppose a $U\in \tau$ then $U\in \mathcal{B}(\tau)=\mathcal{B}(\tau')$ but I can't go anywhere from here...

Could you help me?

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: @tomasz class notes of my teacher

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to assume that they have the same sets with the Baire property.

It is enough to show that if $e\in U$ is $\tau$-open, then it contains a $\tau'$-open $V\ni e$.

Since $G$ is a $\tau$-topological group, there is a $\tau$-open $W\ni e$ with $W=W^{-1}$ and $WW\subseteq U$. But $W$ is $\tau'$-Borel, so $W$ has the Baire property with respect to $\tau'$, and it is not $\tau'$-meagre (since countably many translates cover $G$), so we can find a nonempty $\tau'$-open $V_0$ such that $W\cap V_0$ is comeagre in $V_0$, and we may assume without loss of generality that $V_0$ is symmetric (replacing it with $V_0\cup V_0^{-1}$ if necessary).

Then you can show that $V_0V_0\subseteq WW\subseteq U$. Since $V_0$ is symmetric, $e\in V_0V_0$ and we are done.
Source: [Automatic continuity of group homomorphisms](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Erosendal/PapersWebsite/AutomaticContinuity06.pdf).

Comment: I think this is still your argument but I made it shorter: Consider the identity function $id:(G,\tau)\to(G,\tau')$, which is Borel and thus automatically continuous. By definition of continuity, $\tau'\subseteq\tau$. Use symmetry to see $\tau=\tau'$.

Comment: @EdwardH: Yes, this is the same thing, I just spelled out the proof in this particular case (with some minor simplifications). I did not want to simply apply the result, since that would not be very enlightening for OP, I think.

Comment: I say "particular case", but I'd wager it wouldn't be too hard to show the reverse implication.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying!